# On click load each image separately

Tags: jquery

I am making an image gallery with a load, but I am a bit stuck.

I would like to load each image separately.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slider img:first-child").css("display", "block");
    $("#right").click(function(){
        $(".slider img").each(function(){
            var image = $(this).attr("src")
            alert(image);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

it alerts each, but how can i make it to load it seperately?

Be gentle I am a begginer

Comment: You mean load visually one by one ?

Comment: yes sorry about my bad english

Comment: load all image url:s into an array and use the index? and increase / decrease on right / left button click, if the index were to be too low/big use the highest/lowest index to make it "spin"?

Comment: Can this similar thread help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215390/loading-and-appending-images-progressively

Comment: thank you for everybodys hel i managed to do it

Comment: You should answer to your question to help the community